# Concatenate each element of a vector with each element of another vector

Tags: r, string

```
list1 = c("X", "Y")
list2 = c("1", "2", "3")
```

What I want is

```
c("X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3")
```

How do I do that? Is there maybe a package do to this? I tried `paste()` but it mixes the entries alternatively ("X1, "Y2", "X3").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use either `expand.grid` or `outer` on the `vectors`  to get all the combinations and then we `paste` it together.

With `expand.grid`, the output is a `data.frame` with two columns, we can use `do.call(paste0` to paste each row of the output dataset.

```
 v1 <- do.call(paste0,expand.grid(list1, list2))
 v1[order(v1)]
 #[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "Y1" "Y2" "Y3"
```

Or as mentioned above `outer` is another option which should be very fast for this operation.  The output will be a `matrix`, which can be converted back to `vector` by either using `as.vector` or `c`.

```
 c(t(outer(list1, list2, FUN=paste0)))
 #[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "Y1" "Y2" "Y3"
```

---

Also, the `expand.grid` should work with `list`

```
 list1 <- as.list(list1)
 list2 <- as.list(list2)
 do.call(paste0, expand.grid(list1, list2))
 #[1] "X1" "Y1" "X2" "Y2" "X3" "Y3"
```

Comment: i really gotta master this `expand.grid` thing. I'm always doing the `rep` manually...

Comment: @MichaelChirico.  `expand.grid` is an useful function.  Suppose if we have a list of many elements. doing just `list1 <- list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[4:5], LETTERS[6:7]);
expand.grid(list1)` will get all the possible combinations.

Comment: \*tongue in cheek\* but akrun, what if i want to practice my arithmetic by using `rep`!?

Comment: @MichaelChirico  I remember a particular question (posted sometime back) which asked for specific combination and some combinations were missing so that we cannot use `expand.grid`.  In that case `rep` is the option

Answer (score 6):

```
list1 = c("X", "Y")
list2 = c("1", "2", "3")

as.character(sapply(list1, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, list2)))

# [1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "Y1" "Y2" "Y3"
```

Comment: You could compact it with `c(sapply(list1, paste0, list2))`

Comment: Thanks, I tend to forget about the possibility to pass arguments to `FUN` using `...` of `*apply`. Except for being lazy, are there reasons why `c` is better than `as.character` in this case?

Comment: `as.vector` would be more correct.  But, I just wanted to code golf :-).